# Freeswitch where command history location

Tags: freeswitch

I see the freeswitch have socket mod and they have function:

save_history ([mod_command](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_commands))

> Usage: fsctl save_history
>
> Write out the command history in anticipation of executing a
> configuration that might crash FS. This is useful when debugging a new
> module or script to allow other developers to see what commands were
> executed before the crash.

But i dont know where the history save and after crash i should to to where for tracking the issued.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not using freeswitch but asterisk. If that ( save_history ) point to the history of asterisk console then the original file is in home directory from user that uses the console. Its a dotfile (hidden). With name:

```
$ ls -la ~/.asterisk_history
-rw------- 1 asterisk asterisk 5041 Jul 20 19:23 .asterisk_history
```

Maybe that helps to find the saved file.

Comment: Freeswitch is using .fs_cli_history file in home directory.

Comment: thanks @IvanPenga it exaclty location at home directory